# How to combine random forest from various trained models.

Tags: time-series, classification, random-forest, weka

I am currently working on a training data set which is time dependent. I have divided the dataset into different time zones. For each month, I am training the model with training dataset and class labels. I want to train the data for a past given time interval and then build a vote based approach based on it. For eg: Let say for past 3 months the model has been trained with features and class labels. I want to classify based on last 3-months and vote the label which models agree with based on past 3 months. Is it possible to do this random-forest approach ? How can we combine ensemble of models and build a vote based approach based on this ? Also there is a package in weka which is using ensemble methods. Can we use this approach for the current process.